How to make on the uploaded file setting: "File Privacy on Records" to be set to "Private on Records" by default
Currently, every uploaded file has "File Privacy on Records" set to "Visible to Anyone With Record Access". I want this to be always "Private on Records".
FYI
"Set file access to Set by Record for files attached to records" was unchecked. But does not look like it had any effect.

This setting is tied to the Visibility field on the ContentDocumentLink object.  You can try to build a record-triggered Flow for this.  But, if ContentDocumentLink is not available for Flow, then you'll have to write an Apex trigger.
